# How can I get the rows from the PostgreSQL with specific value. Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How can I get the rows from the PostgreSQL with specific value?
I have this table with columns: id | accountid | dictdata | date |
Inside the dictdata column contains a bunch of dictionary data.

in my models.py

```
class charts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    accoundid= models.IntegerField(default=None,blank=True)
    dictdata=  models.JSONField(default=None,null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "charts"
```

in my python file

```
  data = list(charts.objects.values('dictdata ')) //all dictionary data
  print(data)
```

Example of print(data):

```
   [{'dictdata': {'select': 'bar', 'title': 'some title'}},
   {'dictdata': {'select': 'line', 'title': 'some title'}},
  {'dictdata': {'select': 'pie', 'title': 'some title'}}]
```

how can I get the rows that contains a specific 'select' value? for example I want to get all the rows with 'bar'

```
{'dictdata': {'select': 'bar', 'title': 'some title'}}
```

Comment: is there one list of dicts or many lists containing one dict each?

Comment: one list but many dictionary inside of that list. check my updated question sir

Comment: what is the type of `charts.objects.values('dictdata')` result? Is it already a list?

Comment: you could use a list comprehension to filter that list `[row for row in data if row['dictdata']['select']=='bar']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data inside `dictdata` is a `dict` and is not a `list`, you can filter like this:

```py
Charts.objects.filter(dictdata__select="bar")
```

Comment: this is correct I just added some like this: Charts.objects.filter(dictdata__select="bar").values('dictdata') thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can get the rows from the PostgreSQL with specific value.

```
charts.objects.values('author').distinct()
```